# How to make the UI responsive while calling slow database call?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, responsive-design, database-performance

I have an old web form website. On one page load event on a page, the stored procedure call takes about 20 seconds. It has to fetch over 10 thousands row and the page displays all of them in a big table. Whilst making stored procedure faster is another case, I don't want UI being blocked while calling the SP. The page isn't home page. At the moment, if i click the menu for the page, the browser is just loading for 20 seconds and user will see the page after that.

It would be great if i can show the page first, and show some sort of loading icon while the data is fetching and display the data once it is ready. But I am not sure where to start so I hope someone can guide me.

it's .Net 4 web form application written in VB. Thanks.

Comment: How 'bout using [AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Retrieve-data-from-Database-and-display-on-page-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx) to fetch data from database?

Comment: Some sort of pagination isn't acceptable?

Comment: Hi Tony, the whole report has to be on the page. Thanks.

Hi Doan, i have Ajax here and there for small calls. For this, there is so much going on to rewrite in client side for me i think. Is Ajax the only solution?

Comment: Are you sure it's the database that is slow? If yes, can you optimize the query? If no, maybe it's the drawing function or the client computer that has trouble rendering so much data.

Comment: I found the problem finally .. it's Xmlserializer which is so slow deserializing the xml to .net objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a DispatcherTimer to set the busy indicator running before the heavy task is called (by using a delay).

Then you can disable the indicator once the heavy task is complete.

Works for me.

```
'enable busy indicator & set up the timer
 Private Sub renderControl(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)

        _busyIndicator.IsBusy = True

        Dim timer As New DispatcherTimer
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)
        AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf renderControl_TimerTick
        timer.Start()

    End Sub

 'do your heavy task, disable busy indicator then stop the timer
  Private Sub renderControl_TimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        DoStuff()

        _busyIndicator.IsBusy = False

        'Stop the timer'
        TryCast(sender, DispatcherTimer).[Stop]() 

    End Sub
```

Not sure if this will display the page first, but should show the busy indicator instead of locking up the UI

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach: - use an UpdatePanel with a suitable UpdateProgress animation.

Comment: Thanks but i have a question. UpdatePanel needs some sort of triggering, doesn't it? How can I use it on page load?

Comment: You can use a regular <asp:Timer> control inside the UpdatePanel to raise a Tick event at the interval you want; these will start firing after Page Load and will be processed asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Go with pagination. Get top 10/20 records per page if nothing else is working

Comment: Thanks but we can't use pagination.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX will solve your problem. Ajax lets you easily refresh page contents without reloading whole webpage. Update panel will suffice you in this case. Plus you can use Ajax Accordion for user friendly page loading( loading icon as you said).